# Let $f: R \to R$ be a map of class $C^1$. Show the set P = $\left\{x \in R : f'(x) \neq 0\right\}$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics, education

I've been trying to answer this question, but I have no clue. I'd accept any hints.

Let $f: R \to R$ be a map of class $C^1$. Show the set P = $\left\{x \in R : f'(x) \neq 0\right\}$ is open.

Comment: If  $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function then the set $\{x\in \mathbb R: g(x)\not = 0\}$  is the union of the two open sets $\{x\in \mathbb R: g(x)>0\}$ and $\{x\in \mathbb R: g(x)<0\}$.   If I read the question correctly this should help.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Oh ok, so the union of two open sets is also an open set, right?

Comment: @Mathematician yup! The axioms of a topological space state that the union of open sets is always open (always meaning that even if I take the union of infinitely many open sets, the result will still be open). And, the finite intersection of open sets is open (I can only take the intersection of finitely many open sets. The intersection of infinitely many open sets isn't guaranteed to be open).

Comment: @Mathematician  Right.  Make sure to understand also the posted answer--it uses the fact that the complement of a closed set is open and that the inverse image of a closed set is closed.  Lots to learn here, but it all makes sense after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f'$ is continuous . So inverse image of closed sets is a closed set. as the singleton $\{0\}$ is closed

$\mathbb{R}\setminus P =(f')^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed as $f'$ is continuous. So $(\mathbb{R}\setminus (f')^{-1}(\{0\}))=P$ is open.

Comment: Exactly, but you should do this for $f'$.

Comment: oops . I'll edit it